# Why is g++ saying 'no match for ‘operator=’ when there clearly is, and Visual Studio can see that there is?

Tags: c++, operators, g++, compiler-errors

I'm writing an interface library that allows access to variables within tables (up to a theoretically infinite depth) in an object of type `regula::State`. I'm accomplishing this by overloading `operator[]` within a class, which then returns another of that same class, and calls `operator[]` again as needed. For example:

```
regula::State t;
t["math"]["pi"] = 3.14159;
```

The above is supposed to place the value `3.14159` within variable `pi` in table `math`. Basically, it does this by have `t` return a proxy object representing `math`, which returns another proxy object representing `pi`, to which we actually save the variable. The internals of this aren't really relevant to the question, but here is the function header.

```
LObject LObject::operator[] (const std::string name);
```

Basically, in the example above, the program should call `t`'s `operator[]` with the string `"math"` and return another object, and then call that object's `operator[]` with the string `"pi"`, which returns the final object, and then assigns the value to that one using `operator=`.

```
template <typename T>
T LObject::operator= (const T& value);
```

The `T` returned is just a copy of the `value` passed.

Now, my code produces NO errors in Visual C++ 2008 and works perfectly. But when I try to compile it on Linux with `g++`, I get the following error:

```
../../test/regula-test.cpp:100: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in 
‘L.regula::State::operator[](std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >(((const char*)"Numbers"), ((const std::allocator<char>&)((const 
std::allocator<char>*)(& std::allocator<char>()))))) = Numbers’
../../include/regula.hpp:855: note: candidates are: regula::LObject&
 regula::LObject::operator=(const regula::LObject&)
```

For some reason, `g++` seems to be trying to call `operator=` on `operator[]`, rather than on the returned object like it is supposed to be.

I can actually fix this error by replacing the return type on `operator=` with `void`:

```
template <typename T>
/*T*/ void LObject::operator= (const T& value);
```

But this is not preferable, and besides, I have similar errors in several other locations with a similarly overloaded `operator==`:

```
../../test/regula-test.cpp:153: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘pi == 
L.regula::State::operator[](std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >(((const char*)"pi"), ((const std::allocator<char>&)((const 
std::allocator<char>*)(& std::allocator<char>())))))’
```

I don't understand why this error is occurring in g++, or why it is not occurring in Visual C++. Can anyone shed any light on this or recommend any solutions?

Comment: Post real code. Your samples are broken. `regula::State t["math"]["pi"] = 3.14159;` cannot be a valid C++ statement. The "fixed" declaration of your `operator =` is also broken, because now there's no `T` there

Comment: @AndreyT: I apologize, that line was truncated when it shouldn't have been. I've fixed the sample in question.

Comment: Can you boil it down to a small snippet that demonstrates the error?

Comment: So, when you use the `void` return type on your `operator =`, it compiles and works in GCC?

Comment: @AndreyT: That is correct, for `operator =`. I still get the similar error in all instances of `operator ==` (because obviously that operator needs to return a `bool`, so I can't really change that to void and have it usable.)
@Eclipse: The demonstration of usage is near the top, the error example follows shortly. I don't really know what else I can give you.

Comment: There's nothing obvious that stands out here. We'd need to see more of the implementation to help you. But based on experience and intuition, let me make a wild guess and say that you left out a `typename` disambiguator somewhere in your templated code. MSVC let's you get away with omitting it, while gcc often emits non-intuitive error messages.

Comment: @Charles Salvia: Thank you for your response, I will go through the code and try to see where I would be missing a `typename`. I would post more code, but the entire file is quite large, as is the `LObject` class alone. I thought I had posted all of the relevant parts.

Comment: if you change it to `t["math"]["pi"].operator=(3.14159);`  
or if you change it to `t["math"]["pi"].operator=<double>(3.14159);`  
Does it still give an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Section 5.17 of the ISO standard says

> There are several assignment operators, all of which group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand, **and the type of an assignment expression is that of its left operand**. The result of the assignment operation is the value stored in the left operand after the assignment has taken place; **the result is an lvalue**.

Your `operator=` returns not only the wrong type, but not even an lvalue. Assuming GCC's error message didn't include any other candidates besides `operator=(const regula::LObject&)`, GCC has simply ignored your overload entirely. The `operator=` it mentions is the default, automatically generated function.

On second glance, your `operator[]` also should return a reference. As written, no assignment expressions like your  example should work at all.

So, you should have functions

```
LObject &LObject::operator[] (const std::string name);
```

and

```
template <typename T>
LObject &LObject::operator= (const T& value);
```

Comment: Well it's true that the way operator = is declared is wrong, it's not necessarily true that operator [] is declared wrong.  In point of fact, the specialization for `::std::vector<bool>` defines operator [] to return a _Bit_reference (not a real reference).  _Bit_reference in turn is a class the defines its own `_Bit_reference &_Bit_reference::operator =(bool x)`.

Comment: His operator[] is valid; operator[] isn't required to return an lvalue at all far as I remember (not looking it up now). Point is, he's *using* it as an lvalue.

Comment: Well, the result of `::std::vector<bool>::operator []` is intended to be used as an lvalue too, and it returns a temporary just like his does.

Comment: It's possible, but unlikely, that LObject is a proxy which passes modifications to another object. I'll stand by my advice.

Comment: I ultimately solved my problem by a.) Having operator= be a void function, and b.) Manually casting to an appropriate type whenever the operators are used. Inconvenient, but since I'm basically writing this to scratch my own itch, I've decided I can deal with the compromise. Thanks for all of your input.